# How can I successfully upload a binary on Xcode 7 without this errors?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode7

I archive a binary with Xcode 7, then I validate the binary and when I try to submit to the iOS Appstore, I get the following errors:

- Could not make parent directory for: /Users/DEC/.itmstransporter/softwaresupport/bin/Frameworks/MZXMLMarshalling.framework/Resources/Info.plist
- Could not configure software support.
- An exception has occurred: /Users/DEC/.itmstransporter/softwaresupport/bin/Frameworks/MZXMLMarshalling.framework/Resources/Info.plist (No such file or directory)
- The session's status is FAILED and the error description is 'failed to open ssh session. (16)'

The app runs perfectly in the iOS simulator and on the iPhone 5(iOS 8.3)
and it doest seems like there is an error in the code.

I also try the uploading with the application loader but the same happens.

I think it could be something about xcode 7 or ios 9 because i didnt have this problems before.

Thanks for your help.

[image: screenshot of the errors]

Comment: Add the error code like ITMS-xxxxx,or just a screen shot of it.

Comment: Ok I have just added it.

Comment: @kriOSDeveloper did you find the answer?? I have the same issue....

Comment: @SinaKH I create another instance of the app on itunes connect. Also I used the wifi of my iPhone instead of the normal wifi... and then it magically works. Hope this helps.

Comment: @kriOSDeveloper tnx bro, visit here too:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916146/error-uploading-ios-app-to-the-store/32916224?noredirect=1#comment53660844_32916224

Comment: I was getting these errors too! [I answered this over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770291/ios-app-fail-during-submission/33335547#33335547) I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to solve the issue:

```
$ cd ~/.itmstransporter  
$ rm update_check*  
$ mv softwaresupport softwaresupport.bak  
$ cd UploadTokens  
$ rm *.token
```

(from http://blog.csdn.net/sqc3375177/article/details/49175691)

Comment: what the hell does that even do? fixed the issue. Cheers