# IOS App fail during submission

Tags: ios, app-distribution

i have created my ipa using Xcode 7 and run on ios 9 and it works fine but when i upload it using application loader  it gives me an error .

```
Could not make parent directory for: /Users/Myname/.itmstransporter/softwaresupport/bin/Frameworks/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Resources/Info.plist

ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
```

Any help will be highly appreciated to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with some others and when I changed under Deployment Info > and checked > Requires full screen.

This allowed it to upload.  You just upload with uploader that Xcode uses when the archive is complete.
[image]