# error uploading iOS app to the store

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to upload my app to the store but here is what i get:

What I've done before::

1- removing armv7s from plist.info files

2- disabling compile for active architecture only

[image: error iname]

any idea please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the errors I would speculate that your Architectures build setting includes architectures other than `arm64`, but you specify `arm64` as a required device capability in your Info.plist.  You should either remove that requirement from your Info.plist or set the Architectures build setting to just `arm64`.

Comment: I've only added armv7 and arm64 to the list of required devices... any other ideas my friend ??

Comment: I do not believe you can require both.  `arm64` supersedes `armv7`, so you should likely just specify that, and set your Architectures build setting to `arm64`.  Assuming you really do require `arm64`.

Comment: just removed required devices tag from info.plist and now everything is working as well as required, tnx.
just edit your answer and mention removing tag or... and i'll check that

Comment: And I can't figure out why these were in my plist? As they cause problems and are not true ://

Comment: Yeah, typically you wouldn't want to specify requirements unless they really are requirements.  They're not in there by default, so hard to say how they got there.  If you're using version control, you might be able to figure out when it happened with a blame command.